# JSP Sending HashMap to Controller using <form:>

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, jsp, hashmap

Im trying to send a HasMap with the form tags to my Controller but its giving me the next error:

```
org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'botonesPeriodo[Z00][B1]' of bean class [com.stockcrowd.v2.form.DonacionPermanenteForm]: Cannot access indexed value of property referenced in indexed property path 'botonesPeriodo[Z00][B1]': returned null
```

The structure of the Map on Java is this:

```
HashMap<String, TreeMap<String, Object>>
```

And the form looks like this:

```
<div class="form-input row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<form:input path="botonesPeriodo[${periodo.key}][${boton.key}].importe"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's my Controller the map is an attr from the class DonacionPermanenteForm:

```
@RequestMapping(value="dashboard/permanente", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody int guardarConfiguracion(DonacionPermanenteForm form, MultipartFile file){
```

Comment: Is the hashmap you are talking about inside the DenacionPermanentForm?

Comment: What you are trying to do here is complicated and can be achieved in a better way. Are you bounded to use this data structure?

Comment: Yes, is inside DenacionPermanentForm, witch way do u think its better? im trying to make this the most dynamic way

Comment: What you trying to do is syntactically wrong, you are passing a value to an object, there is no way that Spring will understand how to build that object. Usually this type of mapping are easy to made for simple data structure. What I reccomend to do is to use javascript to build a JSON which represent your object and than map it to yours.

Comment: Yes, i finally go in that way, im building a AJAX request to send the parametes via JSON, thanks for the apply @oeh